# Best practices for deciding if two structural variants are actually the same variant?

Tags: vcf, ngs, software-recommendation

I know that I can use `bcftools isec` to compare two VCF files containing single nucleotide variants (SNVs); it will generate four possible output files: one with all of the unique called SNVs in file 1, one with all of the unique called SNVs in file 2, one with all of the SNVs from file 1 that were also found in file 2, and finally one with all of the SNVs from file 2 that were also found in file 1.

Is there a similar type of tool that will allow one to compare structural variants (SVs) between two VCF files?  I am about to tweak one of my Perl scripts (that currently uses the VCF.pm Perl module to parse VCF files) to perform this calculation (because thus far I have not found any tools designed for SVs) but I thought I would ask in this forum in case anyone else has already invented this wheel.

Comment: It looks like no one has answered yet.  Maybe others would find it easier to help you out if you provided a minimal example of the VCF files that you are trying to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool that you want to use for this task is `bedtools window`.